# Script to filter users

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I create a script that filters users on the system? For example, if there were no user named `mike`:

```
$ echo "root peter pulse mike" | ./script.sh
root peter pulse
```

And other criteria like:

```
-s:  Keep users who have sudo rights
-I:  Keep users with a user ID >= 1000
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
#/bin/bash

grep /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d ":" >> user.txt
```

How can I implement the `if` statements to check that the stdin equals the users for output?

Comment: see `comm` and `sort` commands. and `tr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `grep` the password file, `cut` is enough:

```
cut -f1 -d ":" /etc/passwd
```

... will give you the list of users.

With GNU `grep`'s `-f` option, you can use that list as a file of words to grep the input (your `echo` command):

```
#/bin/bash
grep -F -w -o -f <(cut -f1 -d ":" /etc/passwd)
```

The `-o` option outputs the part of the line that matches the word list specified by the `-f` option (rather than the full line of input).

The `<(...)` syntax is Bash's process substitution. The result of the command is provided as a file, which keeps you from storing the list of users in a temporary file.

Comment: thank you very much for the very detailed help!